# How do I center my search form within a div?

Tags: html, css, search-form

I've got a search form within a div that

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

isn't moving it to the center. Any idea's of how to correct this?

Here's an image link to reference [image: link]

HTML:

```
  <div id="welcome">
    <div class="search-row">
      <div class="postcode-search col-lg-4">
        <div id="postcode-search" class="input-group">
          <input type="text" id="postcode-bar" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter postcode.."/>
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" id="postcode-btn" type="button">FIND STORES</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#welcome {
    height: 220px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
#postcode-search {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
#postcode-bar {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#postcode-btn {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add additional class "**col-lg-offset-4**" to "**postcode-search**".
Because you are using "**col-lg-4**" it adds style **width: 33.33% and float: left**.
So, The style below won't work. This is Useless style.

```
#postcode-search {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

You just have to add one bootstrap grid offset class to center your form within a DIV.

Answer (score 1):

Using a pure CSS solution you can simply do this, using text-align:

```css
#welcome {
    height: 220px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
#postcode-search {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
#postcode-bar {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#postcode-btn {
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="welcome">
    <div class="search-row">
      <div class="postcode-search col-lg-4">
        <div id="postcode-search" class="input-group">
          <input type="text" id="postcode-bar" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter postcode.."/>
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" id="postcode-btn" type="button">FIND STORES</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to width on `#postcode-search` fox example `width: 300px;`  then it will be in center

Comment: So the use of bootstraps col-lg-4 in html isn't enough?

Comment: This won't render a responsive solution.

Comment: @SatejS you can change width in media query or you can use width in %

Comment: @TDP col-lg-4 will be another solution with a col-lc-offset-2. then search bar will also be in middle

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple.

I applied the `text-align:center` style

```
#postcode-search {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Here is a working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d44pu2jy/4/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this css

```
.postcode-search {
  width: 300px; // change value as per requirement
  padding: 30px; // optional
}
.postcode-search.col-lg-4 {
  margin: auto;
}
```

here is a working example https://plnkr.co/edit/FSeAt3TkFeuGvj57hVgS?p=preview